# Can I use a dimmer on a fan IF I only use at 100%?

Tags: electrical, fans, dimmer-switch

I have an IRIS home automation system. I want to put my fan on an IRIS switch however the on/off switches require a neutral - the dimmers do not. The neutral in the box is nearly impossible to get to... so my thoughts were to just use a dimmer but only run it at 100%. I understand its not a good idea to change the speed of a fan using  a dimmer. Considering I have no desire to change the speed with the dimmer and plan on running it at 100%... is this safe?

This is [the dimmer](http://www.lowes.com/pd_339578-1353-45639_0__?productId=3707738&Ntt=iris&pl=1&currentURL=%3FNtt%3Diris&facetInfo=)

## The specs

```
Dimmer or Fan Control           Dimmer
Dimmer and Fan Control Type     Other
Remote Control Included         No
Amps (Amps)                     15.0
Voltage (Volts)                 120.0
Wall Plate Included             No
Color                           White
Color/Finish Family             White
RFI Filter                      Yes
Fan Speed                       N/A
Controller/Dimmer Wattage       600
Phase Type                      Single phase (120/240)
UL Safety Listing               Yes
CSA Safety Listing              No
ETL Safety Listing              No
Collection Name                 Iris
Iris Technology                 Yes
```

Comment: In the most ghetto since yes.  But I wouldn't count on fan lasting as long.

Comment: Most likely this switch sends a low level voltage through the switched device even when the power is off (which is confirmed by reviews of LED's flickering when the switch is off). I don't have enough knowledge to say that would be bad for a fan, but running a switch with a dedicated neutral for the smart components would be the better option IMO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Speaking from experience with the X10 equivalent, no. Even with the switch at 100%, the switch will overheat. You need a switch with a relay. Do it right or not at all; it's not worth burning your house down over.

Comment: OK so lets say I use a switch instead... can I just tie the neutral on the switch to the ground wire? I think its just there to help with the zwave.

Comment: No. While it might work, it is not safe.

Comment: longneck is right.  My comment was written before you showed what type of dimmer it was.  My comment was for the old-standard dumb dimmers.  Which I did have hooked up to a fan and said fan's motor went out after 8 months.